# EF CodeFirst: DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges doesn't work

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-4.1

I use the following code in my Global.asax:

```
DbDatabase.SetInitializer<MyDBContext>
   (new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<MyDBContext>());
```

but it doesn't seem to work.

Although my Model has changed and I'm trying to use one of the newly added table's it just says the table could not be found.

```
Invalid object name 'dbo.TableName'.
```

If I run this however, it seems to work, and the table is being created:

```
DbDatabase.SetInitializer<MyDBContext>(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<MyDBContext>());
```

It does update my database.

What is it I do wrong?

Comment: No I mean IncludeMetadataConvention. Did you remove it? Do you have EdmMetadata table in your db?

Comment: Btw. What do you mean by "model" and "table"?

Comment: By Model I mean one or more of my Entities within my Project.
For example
public class ObjectName
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

And by Table I mean the Table created in my SQL Database.

Comment: Nope. The simple problem is:
My database is being recreated using: DropCreateDatabaseAlways
But is not when using: DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges

Comment: Strange it works without problems for me.

Comment: It turned out to be user permissions on the master database.
Weird that using DropCreateDatabaseAlways is doesn't need permissions on the master database, where IfModelChanges does.

Comment: @reinder: Very interesting. I didn't know that. Post it as answer to your question. I will upvote it. Btw. does it mean that it SQL throws exception which is swallowed by EF?

Comment: Had the same issue with EF 6. Manually dropping the whole DB solved this for me: DROP DATABASE [nameOfDataBase]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It turned out to be user permissions on the master database. Weird that using DropCreateDatabaseAlways is doesn't need permissions on the master database, where IfModelChanges does.

Comment: But does it not need to look in the master database to check your databasemodel? Where as just always drop it does not require any peek in the Master database. The Master database used to contain the systemobjects but it is in newer version in the resource database (see http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190940.aspx about resource database and http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187837.aspx about master database)

Answer (score 10):

For what it's worth, I ran into a lot of trouble with *both* of the DropCreate strategies because Cassini was still running after I closed the browser.  (I had the same problem with IIS Express.)  Because the local web server was still running, `Application_Start` didn't fire again, so the initialization I put there never got executed.

I resolved it by enabling Edit and Continue:

**Project properties** > **Web** > **Debuggers** > **Enable Edit and Continue**

This forces the local web server to close when the browser closes.

Comment: I'm using this in an MVC3 app with cassini. I find that if I rebuild my solution after modifying my model classes and before running again, the drop/create does its job.

Comment: if you are hitting debug or run without debug this is normally the default action in visual studio the only reason i can see this happening is if you modify the code then just re navigate to the site without rebuilding

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue with:

```
Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<BreakAwayContext>());
```

In my case, the database had already existed when i added the above line of code.  I dropped the db and ran my program again and it started working as expected.  Only other conflict might've been the cause is I had been playing with 'Enable-Migrations' on the database.

HTH

Answer (score 1):

This behaviour is expected in case you removed IncludeMetadataConvention:
`modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<System.Data.Entity.Database.IncludeMetadataConvention>();`

Comment: in that case it would, but it isn't the case.